# DateTime format in Ultragrid column

Tags: vb.net, datetime, infragistics, datetime-format, ultrawingrid

I have set a specific format for a column in an `Ultragrid`. But still the `DateTime` is in its default format.

//Code

```
 UltraGridColumn.Header.ToolTipText = Field.FieldDescription
 UltraGridColumn.Format = "d"
```

Even after the above format is set the grid shows the value in the column as `06/06/2013 02:43PM`

But the expected output is `06/06/2013`

Why i'm getting this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Added the column style as `DateTime`.

//Code

```
 UltraGridColumn.Style = ColumnStyle.DateTime
```